# What is the standard docstring for a django model metaclass?

Tags: python, django, metaclass, pep

Models in django can come with a meta class like so:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    """Address model."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta McMetaface."""

        verbose_name = "Address"
        verbose_name_plural = "Addresses"

    address_line = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return address without post code."""
        return self.address_line
```

My metaclass is whimsical at best. Does Python or Django have a standard text for meta classes?

Comment: It's a docstring for documentation. A standard text would serve this purpose purely. This is also valid for a silly name or some content that just repeats the `class` or `def` line above. If there is nothing helpful to write, leave it empty.

Comment: @KlausD. nothing about how it should describe the metaness of the class in the pep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no point in writing a docstring for Meta. It's a standard name that every model defines, and means the same thing in every model.  Just don't write a docstring.

Comment: The reason I wanted to, is that Flake8 is asking me to. I'm just surprised there's no clause in PEP that excludes it or something?

Comment: Reconfigure Flake8!

Comment: Tools are to help you. If you can't tell Flake8 what you want, then use pylint.